# Floating element relative to another element with static start position

Tags: javascript, css

It's hard to explain using words, better look at example i made.

https://jsfiddle.net/yoz6pkh0/

```
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>first</li>
      <li>second</li>
      <li>third</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="filter">FILTER</div>  
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="hero">
  <h1>Hello to Lorem!</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <div class="filter inhero">FILTER</div> 
</div>
<div class="main">
  <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
  ...
  <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
</div>
```

I have the navbar that i hide on scrolling page down and show on scrolling up.
I need to make an element (lets call it FILTER) that on page load is located in hero-section but become sticky to navbar when scrolling to FILTER position or below and vice versa when scrolling up.

I solved the problem in my way but i wonder if any better solution exists? Is it necessary to clone FILTER element?

Comment: [`insertAdjacentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)?

Comment: Have a read into CSS `position: sticky;` you can see the example on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a better solution than cloning the element, you can use this code:
HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
        <li>third</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="hero">
    <h1>Hello to Lorem!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <div class="filter inhero">FILTER</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in enim bibendum neque volutpat maximus. Sed sit amet ante sit amet quam eleifend scelerisque. Aenean mollis, nisi in molestie volutpat, ligula diam laoreet nibh, nec dignissim tortor lectus vitae risus. Aenean mi nisi, fringilla at lacinia at, tincidunt in est. Cras ex enim, sagittis pharetra augue sit amet, dictum accumsan mauris. Duis ultrices magna in pulvinar consequat. Curabitur suscipit hendrerit diam, fringilla interdum purus ullamcorper ac. Pellentesque vestibulum molestie lectus, id lobortis justo ullamcorper sit amet. Mauris nec lorem purus. In aliquet fringilla tempor. Fusce sollicitudin tempor eleifend. Vestibulum nec varius nulla. Nullam quis metus vel ipsum bibendum cursus vel sed quam. In porttitor interdum augue a varius. Maecenas ac enim at mauris blandit egestas at fringilla odio. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in enim bibendum neque volutpat maximus. Sed sit amet ante sit amet quam eleifend scelerisque. Aenean mollis, nisi in molestie volutpat, ligula diam laoreet nibh, nec dignissim tortor lectus vitae risus. Aenean mi nisi, fringilla at lacinia at, tincidunt in est. Cras ex enim, sagittis pharetra augue sit amet, dictum accumsan mauris. Duis ultrices magna in pulvinar consequat. Curabitur suscipit hendrerit diam, fringilla interdum purus ullamcorper ac. Pellentesque vestibulum molestie lectus, id lobortis justo ullamcorper sit amet. Mauris nec lorem purus. In aliquet fringilla tempor. Fusce sollicitudin tempor eleifend. Vestibulum nec varius nulla. Nullam quis metus vel ipsum bibendum cursus vel sed quam. In porttitor interdum augue a varius. Maecenas ac enim at mauris blandit egestas at fringilla odio. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in enim bibendum neque volutpat maximus. Sed sit amet ante sit amet quam eleifend scelerisque. Aenean mollis, nisi in molestie volutpat, ligula diam laoreet nibh, nec dignissim tortor lectus vitae risus. Aenean mi nisi, fringilla at lacinia at, tincidunt in est. Cras ex enim, sagittis pharetra augue sit amet, dictum accumsan mauris. Duis ultrices magna in pulvinar consequat. Curabitur suscipit hendrerit diam, fringilla interdum purus ullamcorper ac. Pellentesque vestibulum molestie lectus, id lobortis justo ullamcorper sit amet. Mauris nec lorem purus. In aliquet fringilla tempor. Fusce sollicitudin tempor eleifend. Vestibulum nec varius nulla. Nullam quis metus vel ipsum bibendum cursus vel sed quam. In porttitor interdum augue a varius. Maecenas ac enim at mauris blandit egestas at fringilla odio. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in enim bibendum neque volutpat maximus. Sed sit amet ante sit amet quam eleifend scelerisque. Aenean mollis, nisi in molestie volutpat, ligula diam laoreet nibh, nec dignissim tortor lectus vitae risus. Aenean mi nisi, fringilla at lacinia at, tincidunt in est. Cras ex enim, sagittis pharetra augue sit amet, dictum accumsan mauris. Duis ultrices magna in pulvinar consequat. Curabitur suscipit hendrerit diam, fringilla interdum purus ullamcorper ac. Pellentesque vestibulum molestie lectus, id lobortis justo ullamcorper sit amet. Mauris nec lorem purus. In aliquet fringilla tempor. Fusce sollicitudin tempor eleifend. Vestibulum nec varius nulla. Nullam quis metus vel ipsum bibendum cursus vel sed quam. In porttitor interdum augue a varius. Maecenas ac enim at mauris blandit egestas at fringilla odio. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in enim bibendum neque volutpat maximus. Sed sit amet ante sit amet quam eleifend scelerisque. Aenean mollis, nisi in molestie volutpat, ligula diam laoreet nibh, nec dignissim tortor lectus vitae risus. Aenean mi nisi, fringilla at lacinia at, tincidunt in est. Cras ex enim, sagittis pharetra augue sit amet, dictum accumsan mauris. Duis ultrices magna in pulvinar consequat. Curabitur suscipit hendrerit diam, fringilla interdum purus ullamcorper ac. Pellentesque vestibulum molestie lectus, id lobortis justo ullamcorper sit amet. Mauris nec lorem purus. In aliquet fringilla tempor. Fusce sollicitudin tempor eleifend. Vestibulum nec varius nulla. Nullam quis metus vel ipsum bibendum cursus vel sed quam. In porttitor interdum augue a varius. Maecenas ac enim at mauris blandit egestas at fringilla odio. </p> 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in enim bibendum neque volutpat maximus. Sed sit amet ante sit amet quam eleifend scelerisque. Aenean mollis, nisi in molestie volutpat, ligula diam laoreet nibh, nec dignissim tortor lectus vitae risus. Aenean mi nisi, fringilla at lacinia at, tincidunt in est. Cras ex enim, sagittis pharetra augue sit amet, dictum accumsan mauris. Duis ultrices magna in pulvinar consequat. Curabitur suscipit hendrerit diam, fringilla interdum purus ullamcorper ac. Pellentesque vestibulum molestie lectus, id lobortis justo ullamcorper sit amet. Mauris nec lorem purus. In aliquet fringilla tempor. Fusce sollicitudin tempor eleifend. Vestibulum nec varius nulla. Nullam quis metus vel ipsum bibendum cursus vel sed quam. In porttitor interdum augue a varius. Maecenas ac enim at mauris blandit egestas at fringilla odio. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in enim bibendum neque volutpat maximus. Sed sit amet ante sit amet quam eleifend scelerisque. Aenean mollis, nisi in molestie volutpat, ligula diam laoreet nibh, nec dignissim tortor lectus vitae risus. Aenean mi nisi, fringilla at lacinia at, tincidunt in est. Cras ex enim, sagittis pharetra augue sit amet, dictum accumsan mauris. Duis ultrices magna in pulvinar consequat. Curabitur suscipit hendrerit diam, fringilla interdum purus ullamcorper ac. Pellentesque vestibulum molestie lectus, id lobortis justo ullamcorper sit amet. Mauris nec lorem purus. In aliquet fringilla tempor. Fusce sollicitudin tempor eleifend. Vestibulum nec varius nulla. Nullam quis metus vel ipsum bibendum cursus vel sed quam. In porttitor interdum augue a varius. Maecenas ac enim at mauris blandit egestas at fringilla odio. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in enim bibendum neque volutpat maximus. Sed sit amet ante sit amet quam eleifend scelerisque. Aenean mollis, nisi in molestie volutpat, ligula diam laoreet nibh, nec dignissim tortor lectus vitae risus. Aenean mi nisi, fringilla at lacinia at, tincidunt in est. Cras ex enim, sagittis pharetra augue sit amet, dictum accumsan mauris. Duis ultrices magna in pulvinar consequat. Curabitur suscipit hendrerit diam, fringilla interdum purus ullamcorper ac. Pellentesque vestibulum molestie lectus, id lobortis justo ullamcorper sit amet. Mauris nec lorem purus. In aliquet fringilla tempor. Fusce sollicitudin tempor eleifend. Vestibulum nec varius nulla. Nullam quis metus vel ipsum bibendum cursus vel sed quam. In porttitor interdum augue a varius. Maecenas ac enim at mauris blandit egestas at fringilla odio. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in enim bibendum neque volutpat maximus. Sed sit amet ante sit amet quam eleifend scelerisque. Aenean mollis, nisi in molestie volutpat, ligula diam laoreet nibh, nec dignissim tortor lectus vitae risus. Aenean mi nisi, fringilla at lacinia at, tincidunt in est. Cras ex enim, sagittis pharetra augue sit amet, dictum accumsan mauris. Duis ultrices magna in pulvinar consequat. Curabitur suscipit hendrerit diam, fringilla interdum purus ullamcorper ac. Pellentesque vestibulum molestie lectus, id lobortis justo ullamcorper sit amet. Mauris nec lorem purus. In aliquet fringilla tempor. Fusce sollicitudin tempor eleifend. Vestibulum nec varius nulla. Nullam quis metus vel ipsum bibendum cursus vel sed quam. In porttitor interdum augue a varius. Maecenas ac enim at mauris blandit egestas at fringilla odio. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in enim bibendum neque volutpat maximus. Sed sit amet ante sit amet quam eleifend scelerisque. Aenean mollis, nisi in molestie volutpat, ligula diam laoreet nibh, nec dignissim tortor lectus vitae risus. Aenean mi nisi, fringilla at lacinia at, tincidunt in est. Cras ex enim, sagittis pharetra augue sit amet, dictum accumsan mauris. Duis ultrices magna in pulvinar consequat. Curabitur suscipit hendrerit diam, fringilla interdum purus ullamcorper ac. Pellentesque vestibulum molestie lectus, id lobortis justo ullamcorper sit amet. Mauris nec lorem purus. In aliquet fringilla tempor. Fusce sollicitudin tempor eleifend. Vestibulum nec varius nulla. Nullam quis metus vel ipsum bibendum cursus vel sed quam. In porttitor interdum augue a varius. Maecenas ac enim at mauris blandit egestas at fringilla odio. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in enim bibendum neque volutpat maximus. Sed sit amet ante sit amet quam eleifend scelerisque. Aenean mollis, nisi in molestie volutpat, ligula diam laoreet nibh, nec dignissim tortor lectus vitae risus. Aenean mi nisi, fringilla at lacinia at, tincidunt in est. Cras ex enim, sagittis pharetra augue sit amet, dictum accumsan mauris. Duis ultrices magna in pulvinar consequat. Curabitur suscipit hendrerit diam, fringilla interdum purus ullamcorper ac. Pellentesque vestibulum molestie lectus, id lobortis justo ullamcorper sit amet. Mauris nec lorem purus. In aliquet fringilla tempor. Fusce sollicitudin tempor eleifend. Vestibulum nec varius nulla. Nullam quis metus vel ipsum bibendum cursus vel sed quam. In porttitor interdum augue a varius. Maecenas ac enim at mauris blandit egestas at fringilla odio. </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    .container {
      margin: 0px 200px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    nav {
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
      margin: 0;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      top: 0px;
      transition: top 0.5s;
    }
    .filter {
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: flex;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    li {
      padding: 15px;
    }
    .main {
      padding: 50px 200px;
    }
    .hero {
      padding: 150px 200px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: bisque;
      height: 250px;
    }
```

JS:

```
let filter = document.getElementsByClassName("filter")[0];
let fixed = false;
let filterTop = filter.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (filter.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 50 && !fixed) {
    filter.style.position = 'fixed';
    filter.style.top = '50px';
    fixed = true;
  } else if (window.scrollY <= filterTop - 50 && fixed) {
    filter.style.position = 'static';
    filter.style.top = '';
    fixed = false;
  }

});
```

What I've done here is removing the clone (and the styles related to it ) and making the position of the filter fixed or static according to the scroll.

Comment: Really easy solution, thx.